# how to use distinct in DecryptByKey

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to get distinct values but values are encrypted;

For Example :

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DecryptByKey(UserId)) from user
```

Comment: Is there any problem in using `Distinct` keyword ?

Comment: That's a tough one. In order to get a distinct you need decrypted values. But when you decrypt values then these values are clear-text on the server and are probably logged. The only solution I can think of is applying a hash to the decrypted values and then getting a distinct on them (in a table variable). The real problem in this question is how to process encrypted data on a server while avoiding the log.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert()` function like this:

```
Select distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DecryptByKey(UserId)) From user
```